# Converting the index of 1D array to access 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

```
void dgem(int n, double *A, double *B, double *C)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){

            double cij = C[i+j*n]; /* cij = C[i][j] */

            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                cij += A[i+k*n] * B[k+j*n]; /*cij = A[i][k]*b[k][j]*/
                C[i+j*n] = cij; /* C[i][j] = cij */
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This code is from Computer_Organization_and_Design_5th

Is it right? `double cij = C[i+j*n];`

As far as I know, it should be `C[i*n + j]`

```
int main(void){

    double A[4][4] = {1,2,3,4,
                      5,6,7,8,
                      9,10,11,12,
                      13,14,15,16};
    double * a = &A[0][0];

    int n = 4;
    printf("%f %f %f %f", *(*(A+1)+3), A[1][3], a[1*n + 3], a[1 + 3*n]); /* 
when i == 1 and j == 3 */

    return 0;

}
```

OUTPUT:

> 8.000000 8.000000 8.000000 14.000000

When I try with gcc, it doesn't make sense...

Comment: Yes the above is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain the reason that [i][j] becomes [i + j*n]?

Comment: "Mangled 2D arrays" is antique stuff from early 90s. In modern C you always access arrays as `[i][j]`. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: I appreciate all the answers thanks!

Comment: @Simon - do not post pictures of text -- post the text (properly indented by 4-spaces). Your text will take ~120-bytes to store, your images will take 100 times that -- and -- we are not going to retype text from your pictures to test your code. Help us help you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I removed the picture.. really sorry. I should have been kinder about the question. From now on, i will try to be polite. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: No big deal, you are new here -- you get a couple of screw-ups without being dinged. The way you can help us help you is to always post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with any data necessary to your question. That way we can compile your code, find the problems, and confirm proper operation before helping you with an answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below statement

```
double cij = C[i+j*n];
```

is correct. To understand this Lets assume `double ptr[3] = {1.5,2.5,3.5]` where `ptr` is array of three double variable. Now how will you access `ptr[0]` or `ptr[1]` etc.

```
 ----------------------------------------
|    1.5   |   2.5   |   3.5   |   4.5   |
-----------------------------------------
0x100     0x108    0x116     0x124     0x132 <-- lets say starting address 
LSB                                                 of ptr is 0x100
|
ptr
```

for `row = 1`

```
ptr[row] == *(ptr + row * sizeof(ptr[row]))
2.5      == *(0x100 + 1*8)
2.5      == *(0x108)
2.5      == 2.5
```

From above you can't have `*(ptr*8 + row)` it should be `*(ptr + row*8)`.

Similarly if `ptr` is `2D` array like `double ptr[2][3]` then

`ptr[row][col] == *( *(ptr + row) + col*8)`

Similarly in your case valid one is  `C[i + j*n]` not `C[i*n +j]`

**Edit** :-
you have an `2D array` like below

```
double A[4][4] = { {1,2,3,4} , {5,6,7,8} , {9,10,11,12} , {13,14,15,16} };
```

And

```
double *a = &A[0][0];
```

Now it looks like

```
    A[0]          |   A[1]        |   A[2]           |   A[3]             |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  16 |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x100 0x108...................0x156.......................0x156 (assume that 0x100 is starting address of A)
  A
  a
 LSB -->
```

Now when you do `a[1*n + 3])` How internally its expanded

```
a[1*n + 3]) == *(a + (1*n + 3)  /*note that a is double pointer, it increments by 8 bytes
a[1*n + 3]) == *(0x100 + (1*4 + 3) *8)
a[1*n + 3]) == *(0x100 + 56)
            == *(0x156)
            ==  8 /* it prints 8.000000 */
```

And when you do `a[1+3*n])`  How internally its expanded

```
a[1+3*n]) == *(a + (1+3*n)*8)
a[1+3*n]) == *(0x100 + (1+3*4)*8)
a[1+3*n]) == *(0x100 + 96)
          == *(0x196)
          == 14 /* it prints 14.000000 */
```

When you do `*(*(A+1) +3))` it internally expanded as

```
*(*(A+1) +3)) == *( *(0x100 +1*32) + 3*8) /* A+1 means increment by size of A[0] i.e 32 */ 
*(*(A+1) +3)) == *( *(0x132) + 24)
*(*(A+1) +3)) == *( 0x132 + 24 ) == *(156)
*(*(A+1) +3)) == 8 /*it prints 8.000000 */
```

And When you do `A[1][3]` which is same as above case.

Comment: Could you please see the APPENDED PICTURE?     Why is the value different between A[i][j] and A[i + j*n]?

Comment: Hi @Simon I modified my answer. if any other query plz ask.

Comment: Thanks. You are such an outstanding and nice person. Then in my code, if i want to access A[i][j], i should do a[i\*n + j]. But you said that when accessing C[i][j], C[i + j\*n] is right. I confused this part.

Comment: Note that `C` you declared as single double pointer, And `A` you declared as 2D array, so both are different. And don't confuse with `n` because you fixed it as `4`.

Comment: Thank you. I will brood over your excellent answer with the problem.